# AngularJS - Select tag's ng-model value not showing up

Tags: angularjs, select, dropdown, angularjs-ng-model

I am using AngularJS. I have a select tag. The tag's value is bound by `ng-model`. The `ng-model` variable has a value (coming from server). That value does not show up in the select dropdown tag. It shows up in a normal text box though.

How can I get the `ng-model` value ('blue' for below example) show up in the dropdown?

Please refer - http://jsfiddle.net/9w5XT/2446/

```
<select ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected"
        data-ng-options="blisterPackTemplate as blisterPackTemplate.name for 
                         blisterPackTemplate in blisterPackTemplates">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
</select>
<hr>
<input type="text" ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected" />
```

Comment: Use <input type="text" ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected.name" />

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<select ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected"
        data-ng-options="blisterPackTemplate.name as blisterPackTemplate.name for 
                         blisterPackTemplate in blisterPackTemplates">
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akjbcpcL/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have the same model in array which you use in dropdown like this which you use for selected.

```
<div ng-app="App" >
     <div ng-controller="ctrl">
       <select  ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected"
         data-ng-options="blisterPackTemplate.name as blisterPackTemplate.name 
        for blisterPackTemplate in blisterPackTemplates">
        <option value="">Select Account</option>
       </select>
       <hr>
        <input type="text" ng-model="blisterPackTemplateSelected" />
     </div>       
    </div>

        var app=angular.module('App', []);

    function ctrl($scope){
        $scope.itemList=[];
        $scope.blisterPackTemplateSelected = 'blue'
        $scope.blisterPackTemplates=[{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"},{id:4,name:"c"},{id:3,name:"blue"}]
    }
```